# IOS Create uitableview delegate in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I create the template A. In this template, i create a table and have data. When i create class B. @interface B: A. If B have tableView, the tableView in Template A just recognize UITableView Delegate + UITableViewDatasource in class B. 
How can recognize UITableView Delegate + UITableViewDatasource of each tableView in another class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "template", it's a class. So you create class A, inside you set up a tableView and assign its delegate and data source to `self`. Then you create class B as a subclass of class A.
Any object of class B will still be the delegate and data source to its own table.
If you want to change the delegate and data source of the table you can just assign its properties `.dataSource` and `.delegate` the way you want.

Update:

It's tough to understand what you're saying, but maybe you're trying to have the same delegate and datasource to any subclass of A.

In that case, here's what you do: Create a class that will be the datasource and delegate. Let's say it's called ADD.
Start with creating a property:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> tvDelegate;
```

In A's initializer, do:

```
self.tvDelegate = [ADD new];
self.tableView.datasource = tvDelegate;
self.tableView.delegate = tvDelegate;
```

Then any subclass will use the same delegate and datasource, namely an instance of ADD.

Comment: oh, thanks for you help, but i mean template is the class be using at some another class, i setup UI in this and another class be create as a subclass of class A, it just the name i call.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140392/ios-can-i-put-all-delegate-method-on-another-class-inherit-the-delegates-into-a) to another question that will help you out with this.